# Chess Board is blank, how can i fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently trying to make a chess game with python 3.10.9 using pygame, but i've already encountered a problem, my chess board is blank.
I checked the code over and over but i can't find any error.
Here is my code:

main.py

```py
import pygame
import sys

from const import *
from game import Game

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Chess')

        self.game = Game()

    def mainloop(self):
        while True:
            self.game.show_bg(self.screen)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()




            pygame.display.update                    

main = Main()
main.mainloop()
```

game.py

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Show Methods
    def show_bg(self, surface):
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                if (row+col)%2==0:
                    color = (234, 235, 200)
                else:
                    color = (119, 154, 88)

                rect = (col*SQSIZE, row*SQSIZE, SQSIZE, SQSIZE)

                pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect)
```

const.py

```py
COLS=8
ROWS=8
SQSIZE=WIDTH//COLS
```

Comment: Isn't `pygame.display.update` a method and therefore should be called like so `pygame.display.update()`?

Comment: `SQSIZE=WIDTH//COLS` is suspicious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.display.update()` not `pygame.display.update`